# Where does this value from Stack come from?

Tags: c#

```
 public static double izracunaj_skladovni_stroj(Queue<char> postfiksni_izraz)
    {
        Stack<double> skladovni_stroj = new Stack<double>();

        while (postfiksni_izraz.Count > 0)
        {
            char podatek_ = postfiksni_izraz.Dequeue();

            if (jeOperand(podatek_))
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("Podatek trenutni: "+podatek_);
                skladovni_stroj.Push(podatek_);
                foreach (var item in skladovni_stroj)
                {
                 Console.Write("Skladovni stroj "+item + " ");   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(skladovni_stroj);
                double x = skladovni_stroj.Pop();
                double y = skladovni_stroj.Pop();

                double rezultat = 0;

                switch (podatek_)
                {
                    case '^':
                        rezultat = Math.Pow(y,x);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        rezultat = y * x;
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        rezultat = y / x;
                        break;
                    case '+':
                        rezultat = y + x;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        rezultat = y - x;
                        break;

                    default:
                        rezultat = 0;
                        break;
                }
                skladovni_stroj.Push(rezultat);
            }
        }

        // na skladu mora ostat samo rezultat
        return (skladovni_stroj.Count != 0) ? skladovni_stroj.Pop() : Int32.MinValue;
    }
```

**So I am having a problem with wrong value being pushed to "skladovni_stroj", which then leads to wrong result being saved.**

**For example:**
Function gets queue named "postfiksni_izraz" which value is: "12+3+"

Then I save the char to new variable named "podatek_".
[image]

when I console write the variable "podatek_" it outputs he right value, but when I try to push it in the Stack named "skladovni_stroj", it pushes in the wrong value "49" instead of "1".
[image]

... and this is the console output of Stack: "skladovni stroj" and current char : "podatek_":

[image]

Comment: There is a difference between the char `'1'` and the value `1`. Char '1' has unicode value 49

Comment: That is the issue probably...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to @HansKesting I got an answer that solved my issue:

```
skladovni_stroj.Push(Char.GetNumericValue(podatek_));
```